# Problems using apache rewriterules

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

Hi here are my rewrite conditions:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/(myapp)/ - [E=MY_URL:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_URL} 1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I'm trying to redirect everything that goes to http://www.example.com/myapp/
to https://www.example.com/myapp/ but it seems that I'm getting an infinite loop, I tried putting 2 conditions so if HTTPS was on it **shouldn't** redirect, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
i change it to the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

I don't understand the part [R=301], but it still giving me the **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error

Comment: You didn't do a client-side redirect. there's no `[R=301]`, so it's purely an internal rewrite. since it's internal only, you come in no-ssl, set your env var, then you re-enter the rewrite, with that env var still set.

Comment: i updated the post, i removed the env var

Comment: `r=301` sends a http 301 redirect header to the client, saying "go here", and here is your new https url. without that, you're only doing an "inside apache only" internal rewrite, and the client itself will continue using non-ssl requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figure it out thanks to a friend and this [link](http://code.haleby.se/2015/12/11/redirect-http-to-https-in-wordpress-running-behind-a-google-http-load-balancer/),

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

i dont know why `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` doesnt work here on my rules (apache 2.4), so i used  `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` instead, works like a charm